# Does inequality follow from Jensen's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

As of now, I am covering some *basic* material on convex functions from the text Real Analysis by Royden. Further, I have come across Jensen's Inequality, which states,

Let $\varphi$ be a convex function on $(-\infty, \infty)$, $f$ an integrable function over $[0,1]$, and $\varphi \circ f$ also integrable over $[0,1]$. Then

$$\varphi\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right)\leq\int_0^1\left(\varphi \circ f\right)(x)\,dx.$$

---

My question is, using this, can it be shown that for an integrable function $f$ over $[0,1]$,

$$\sin\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right)\leq\int_0^1\sin(f(x))\,dx\ ?\tag{*}$$

---

I *believe* this could be argued, or proved rather, by defining $\varphi(x):=\sin(x)$. Moreover, since
$\varphi''(x) = -\sin(x)$, it follows that $\varphi$ is convex on $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Using properties of the sine function,

$$\int_0^1|\left(\varphi \circ f\right)(x)|\,dx = \int_0^1|\sin(f(x))|\,dx\leq\int_0^11\,dx<\infty.$$

That is, $\varphi \circ f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$. Therefore, the inequality $(*)$ follows directly from Jensen's Inequality.

Comment: Not true, sine is convex at first half of period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contradiction use,
$$f(x)=x^2$$
Then you would get that
$$\sin\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)\approx0.33\nleq0.31\approx\int_0^1\sin(f(x))dx$$
In addition, $\sin$ is not convex on $[0,1]$, it is concave, hence the opposite equality would hold.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x)$ is only convex for some portions of $(-\infty, \infty)$, not for all of it, so Jensen's inequality doesn't hold. For a simple counter-example, try $f(x) = x$. Then $(*)$ is $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq1-\cos(1)$$

which is not true.